# How to find points fall within a buffer zone in R?

Tags: r

I have two data frames imported from txt files -- the sampling points and the station locations.

The sampling points data frame

```
X   Y   Z
346449.30   576369.65   86.93
346449.55   576368.24   87.16
346449.29   576368.17   79.08
346449.83   576366.86   88.23
346449.97   576365.42   84.97
346449.91   576362.22   86.59
346449.74   576363.65   88.87
346449.61   576363.59   84.99
346449.50   576363.54   81.33
```

The station locations data frame

```
Station x   y
1   346479.720  576349.710
2   346575.380  576361.530
3   346685.540  576303.180
4   346722.820  576412.680
5   346514.780  576406.140
6   346813.130  576435.830
7   346748.880  576304.090
8   346825.830  576402.800
```

So i would like to know how to find and label points (from the sampling data frame) that fall within a buffer zone (e.g. 3 meters buffer radius generated from each of the stations from the second data frame)?

This is what i would like to get:

```
X   Y   Z   Station
346449.30   576369.65   86.93   1
346449.55   576368.24   87.16   1
346449.29   576368.17   79.08   1
346449.83   576366.86   88.23   2
346449.97   576365.42   84.97   2
346449.91   576362.22   86.59   3
346449.74   576363.65   88.87   4
346449.61   576363.59   84.99   5
346449.50   576363.54   81.33   5
346449.51   576365.07   89.38   5
346449.36   576365.01   84.93   5
346449.24   576366.46   88.70   5
346448.93   576367.83   86.75   5
```

I am new in R so any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Not clear about how you got the 10-13 rows in the expected output.

Comment: @sam_n, can you show expected output using the data you have?  Your expected output last row has Z value 86.75, which doesn't exist in your sampling data.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't mean to include the last 4 rows in your expected output?  Also, how is buffer zone computed?

Comment: The third data frame is just a dummy example to explain what i am looking for, therefore the the "Station" id on the forth column is not the actual output. The buffer zones (circular windows) should be generated from the second data frame.The radius of the zones (windows) should be 3m from the the center points. Appreciate if anyone could show me the way to compute buffer zones and extract point fall within the zones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you simply want to add id of the nearest station within 3 meters of the sampling data points to your sampling data.frame one solution would be:

```
# get a matrix with the squares of the euclidian distances
mx  <-  outer(seq(nrow(sampleData)),
              seq(nrow(stations)),
              # return the square of the euclidian distance
              function(i,j){
                  (sampleData[i,'X'] - stations[j,'x'])^2 + 
                  (sampleData[i,'Y'] - stations[j,'y'])^2
              })


# maximum distance to consider
d = 3

# get rid of distances greater than 3 meters away 
mx[mx>d^2] <- NA

index  <-  apply(mx,
                 1,
                 # returns the number of the nearest row in `stations` that is less than 3 meters away
                 function(x){
                     if(all(is.na(x)))
                         return(NA)
                     x[is.na(x)] <- F
                     which.max( x == min(x,na.rm=T) )
                 })

sampleData$station <- stations$station[indx]

# a comma delimited list of stations with distance < 3
sampleData$closeStations  <-  apply(mx,
                 1,
                 # returns the number of the nearest row in `stations` that is less than 3 meters away
                 function(x){
                     if(all(is.na(x)))
                         return(NA)
                     paste0(stations$Station[x],sep = ',')
                 })
```

using `outer` and `apply` may make the solution run faster, but if you're having trouble with it, it may be easier to debug using a `for` loop instead:

```
# maximum distance to consider
d = 3

distanceToNearestStation <- 
nearestStation <- numeric(0)
nearestStations <- character(0)
for(i in seq(nrow(sampleData))){

    # square of the euclidian distances from this data point to the stations
    distances <- sqrt((sampleData[i,'X'] - stations[,'x'])^2 + 
                  (sampleData[i,'Y'] - stations[,'y'])^2 )

    # get rid of distances greater than 3 meters away 
    # distances[distances>d] <- NA

    # all the stations are too far away or something is wrong with this data point
    if(all(is.na(distances)))
        next

    # record the nearest station to this data point
    distanceToNearestStation[i] <- min(distances,na.rm=T)
    nearestStation[i] <- which.max( distances == min(distances,na.rm=T) )

    # comma delimeted list of stations within 3 meters
    distanceIsClose <- distance < 3
    distanceIsClose[is.na(distanceIsClose)] <- F

    nearestStations[i] <- paste0(paste0(stations$Station[distanceIsClose],sep = ','))
}

range(distanceToNearestStation)

sampleData$station <- stations$station[nearestStation]

# number of data points within 3 meters of a station
table(distanceToNearestStation <= 3)

# data points within 3 meters of a station
subset <- sampleData[distanceToNearestStation<= 3,]

# save to individual files. 
for(s in unique(subset$station))
    write.csv(subset[subset$station == s,],
              file.path('My/Favorite/Directory'# note there is no trailing slash
                        ,paste('station',s,'data.csv')))
```

Comment: Jthorpe, i got this error message "Error in stations$station[index] : invalid subscript type 'list' with your script. Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: Yes, I forgot the `,na.rm=T` in the call to `min(x)`. That caused `min` to return a `NA` , which caused `which.max` to return a value of length zero, and when the return values don't all have the same length (`1` in this case), apply returns a list instead of the vector that we wanted. (fixed in the above code)

Comment: Jthorpe, i m still having problem to run the script. I have no idea whats wrong with that. Any way that i can send you my real dataset?

Comment: I made a simpler version of the script that don't use `apply` or `outer`.  If you are still getting errors, post the errors here.

Comment: there are two error messages:Error in `[.data.frame`(stations, j, "x") : object 'j' not found

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "station", value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 3949

Comment: The first error was from the `j` index which i had left in from the first block of code (fixed).  The second error was cause by the first

Comment: two errors appeared:                                                                           Error in nearestStation[i] <- which.max(distances == min(distances, na.rm = T)) : 
  replacement has length zero
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
 
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "station", value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA,  : 
  replacement has 207 rows, data has 3949

Comment: Sounds like there may be some quirks in your dataset.  Since the for loop went long enough to give errors, it didn't quit on the first go around.  You might check on the errors using `head(warnings())`, check which iteration failed by typing `i` in the console and inspect the row that caused the error `sampleData[i,c('X','Y')]`.  It might be obvious what the problem is, otherwise post the errors and

Comment: again, two error messages: Error: object 'x' not found

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "station", value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 3949  And i tried the head(warnings()) as well, the return and the result showed "NULL".

Comment: Try it  now.   I changed 'if(all(is.na(x)))' which caused the first error to 'if(all(is.na(distances)))'.  The second error was caused by the firs.

Comment: One error appeared: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "station", value = integer(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 3949

Comment: In your sample data, all the data points are between 32 and 36 meters away from the station.  I think you're getting errors because none of your data points are close enough to the stations.  I commented out the line that enforces the distance requirement.   See if it runs now.

Comment: there is no error message. However, i found out that the output included all points from the original sampleData, even some of the points are not fall within the 3m distance from the stations. The actual expected output should contain only points fall within the 3m distance. So how to extract points fall within 3m radius from each station and then export them as individual data frame (e.g. dat_1.txt for points fall within Station 1, dat_2.txt for points fall within Station 2, ........dat_n.txt for points fall within Station n)?

Comment: finally it works. BTW, is there a way to export the outputs (the clipped points within each circular window) to individual txt files? Each of the exported txt file should contains only points fall within the distance from the station.

Comment: If you have trouble with the directory, use `file.choose()` to get a valid path

Comment: eventually the script produced the outputs i wanted. BTW, it there any way to make the script runs faster? it took extremely long hours when i applied to my real dataset.

Comment: It's inevitable that doubling the size of either dataset will double the running time.  However using `outer` and `apply` (as in the first solution) would likely run faster (assuming you have enough RAM memory on your machine).   Those functions worked on you example dataset, but there are some quirks in your real dataset that kept it from working properly (missing values, improperly formatted values, etc).  data cleaning is almost always required with large datasets, which is likely in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I found out that some of the stations are too close to each other, and there are points fall within two station buffer zones. So is there any way to assign a new variable/column (e.g. "Over") to each output table that indicating over-lapping points such as "1257" - where this point belongs to both Station 12 and Station 57? and "3400" for points that only belong to the Station 34 without overlapping?

Comment: I added a couple of lines that should return a comma delimited list of stations.  (comma delmited so you can tell the difference between [1234], [12,34], [1,2,34], etc.

Comment: For the second script, error message appeared --- "There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)" right after the looping function and before the script line of "range(distanceToNearestStation)".